# Rented Property: Install Nest

Tags: thermostat, boiler, nest

I have a Worcester boiler (Greenstar HE?), with a [TR2](http://www.gotogasdocs.co.uk/f/m/Worcester/Other%20Equipment%20&%20Information/tr2-room-thermostat-instructions.pdf) thermostat. I was looking at replacing the thermostat with a Nest (or equivalent).

To complicate matters, I'm in a rented property, so I cannot do any work that could not be easily reverted when moving out. That would include any changes to the wall mounting.

Ideally, I'd be able to remove the TR2 unit from the wall mount, and attach the Nest to the same mount.

Is this possible?

Comment: We'd need much more documentation about how the TR2 communicates with the controller -- is your boiler a modulating system?!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Nest thermostat you want is compatible with your boiler, there is no issue in replacing the existing one. Most if not all thermostats are designed to be removed in a non-destructive manner.

Mounting it may require drilling new holes. When your lease is up, simply reattach the old one. Any new holes if needed would be covered up by the thermostat, hence should not be held against you by any reasonable person.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the TR2 is a proprietary unit designed to work specifically with your boiler. It *may* be possible to connect a NEST, but I'd have to see a schematic for your unit (which I wasn't able to find).

It's not likely that the NEST will mount in the same wall bracket, and installing the NEST *may* require modifications to the boiler.  Try contacting NEST, to see if the unit is compatible with your equipment.

Also, since it's a rented property, you should probably have the owner's permission before you make any modifications.